Why are the energy eigenvalues not also dependent in time?
I've just started reading Griffiths' chapter on time-dependent perturbation theory. We start with a system which at $t=0$ has only two eigenstates $\psi_a,\psi_b$. i.e. at $t=0$ the system is uniquely determined as $$\psi=c_a\psi_ae^{iE_at/\hbar}+c_b\psi_be^{iE_bt/\hbar}.$$ According to Griffiths then, the time evolution of the system simply requires that the coefficients $c_a,c_b$ vary in time. But if the Hamiltonian changes, why should it not be the case that at a later time $t$, that the energy eigenvalues also change? This may be a silly question, but as I understand it, at every instant in time the general wavefunction should be uniquely written as a linear combination of the eigenstates at that particular moment in time, no? Why is this evolution captured by the coefficients alone? Or is there some underlying assumption I am missing?

First, switch off the time-dependent perturbation.  We know that the set of all eigenstates $\lbrace \phi_a \rbrace$ of the unperturbed $H_0$ forms a complete basis of the Hilbert space.  Therefore, at any moment, even with the perturbation, any state can still be written as
$$
\psi(t) = \sum_{a} \tilde{c}_a(t) \phi_a.
$$
As the OP has noted, $\lbrace \phi_a \rbrace$ is no longer the set of eigenstates of $H(t)$.  But there is nothing wrong using a non-eigen-basis.
And then nothing prevents me from redefining
$$
\tilde{c}_a(t) = c_a(t) e^{iE_a t/\hbar}.
$$
This has nothing to do with Shrodinger equation at all; I am merely pulling out a c-number factor.
Why do we want to pull out that factor, though?  Because when you plug this form into Schrodinger equation and do perturbation theory, you get nice cancellations and life is made a little bit easier.

Ah, I see. The fact that the basis is complete to start with means that we can still express the system in a linear combination of eigenfunctions at $t=0$, and the exponential term with the energy eigenvalues can be counter-balanced (or absorbed) into the time-dependent coefficients. This makes it very clear.

In general, if the Hamiltonian is time-dependent, its eigenvalues and eigenvectors also will. A silly example could be the spin one-half Hamiltonian
$$
H = E_0\cos(\omega t) \sigma_z + J\sin(\omega t) \sigma_x
$$
Where $\sigma_z,\sigma_x$ are the Pauli matrix  in z and x directions. You can see that at $t=0$, this Hamiltonian is a multiple of $\sigma_z$, so its eigenvalues are $\pm E_0$ and eigenvectors $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$. But in $t=\pi/2\omega$, the eigenvalues are $\pm J$ and eigenvectors $|\pm\rangle$, where
$$
|\pm\rangle = {1\over\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle \pm |1\rangle)
$$

Let's suppose we choose the eigenvectors of $\sigma_z$ to describe the state of the system. Since they span the hole Hilbert space, we could use them to represent the state of the system at any time. But they only are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian in $t=0$, which means that the time evolution of the coefficients will be more complex than just the phase $e^{\pm E_0t/\hbar}$.
Fortunately, in this example we can write the Schrodinger explicitly. We write
$$
|\psi\rangle = c_0(t)|0\rangle + c_1(t)|1\rangle
$$
And by Schrodinger equation, se have
$$
i\hbar \dot{c_0} = E_0\cos(\omega t) c_0 + J\sin(\omega t) c_1
$$
$$
i\hbar \dot{c_1} = -E_0\cos(\omega t) c_1 + J\sin(\omega t) c_0
$$
The difficulties in solving equations like the above is that what justify the perturbation theory.
I recommend you the ammonia maser chapter in Feynman lectures, where he solves similar equations without perturbation theory, but with some approximations.


But if the Hamiltonian changes, why should it not be the case that at a later time $t$, that the energy eigenvalues also change?

Eigenvalues of a time-dependent Hamiltonian indeed do change in time. But eigenvalues of the time-independent part $H_0$ do not. The latter operator is often used to define a basis (a complete set of linearly independent functions) which we then use to define the expansion coefficients of $\psi(t)$, even when total Hamiltonian is different and depends on time.

...as I understand it, at every instant in time the general wavefunction should be uniquely written as a linear combination of the eigenstates at that particular moment in time, no?

This is possible, but not necessary; one can express $\psi$ as linear combination of any other set of functions. To make sure we can expand any $\psi$ and represent it in a unique way by expansion coefficients $c_n$, we want to use a set of functions that together form a basis. By assumption (postulates of QT), eigenfunctions $\Phi_n$ (normalizable to 1) and improper eigenfunctions $\phi_f$ (not normalizable to 1) of any Hamiltonian form a basis, meaning we can express $\psi$ as infinite sum over the discretely indexed eigenfunctions, plus integral over the continuously indexed improper eigenfunctions:
$$
\psi(\mathbf r) = \sum_n c_n \Phi_n(\mathbf r) + \int \gamma_f \phi_f(\mathbf r) df,
$$
where $\gamma_f$ is a continuous "expansion coefficient" of the "continuously indexed" improper eigenfunction $\phi_f$, and $f$ is the Hamiltonian eigenvalue in the continuous part of the spectrum.
But eigenfunctions of any different Hamiltonian (which may be different, and even depend on time) also form a complete basis, which we can use. So we have great a freedom in choosing the basis into which we expand $\psi$ and which we use to define $c_n$'s.

Why is this evolution captured by the coefficients alone? Or is there some underlying assumption I am missing?

Because if basis functions are time-independent, as they often are due to choice of basis, then the only thing left that can depend on time are the coefficients. This is the simplest case: the basis functions $\Phi_n,\phi_f$ are fixed, and the expansion coefficients $c_n,\gamma_f$ change in time. Sometimes we use different representation, where the coefficients contain only a part of the time evolution, and the other part is tucked away (so-called interaction picture).
But of course, we could also express $\psi$ also in terms of time-dependent eigenfunctions of the total Hamiltonian $H(t)$ that varies in time. This is useful in case the variation is very slow compared to resonant "transition" frequencies of $H_0$. A brief description of this approach is in this answer of mine:
QM: General Solution of TDSE
